# How to find Current location location without GPRS?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, location

I want to develop an app for iPhone. In that i need to find the current location(not exactly).
I have not used GPRS. Is it anyway to find that?

Comment: Did you mean GPS (Global Positioning System)?

Comment: yes. can i find using network tower using currently?

Comment: Yes. And wifi too. But I'm not sure if you can specify not to use GPS. However, you can set the accuracy to the lowest level, so iOS will use the "worst" available location method (should be cell towers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll only get location data on iOS from CLLocationManager. It may (or may not) use GPS; that's dependent on the device, how exact you want the data to be, etc.

The reason why that is so is because Apple gives users an option to *choose* if they want their location data accessed by an app. If you're looking for a way to get around that, it's not possible.

Comment: To add to this, `CLLocationManager` will start with a location by cell tower triangulation. If you specified a more precise location it will start up the GPS and will try to get a good signal, but it will return all step in between. If the user does not allow you to use their location then that it, there is not around this.